# Powershell Regex matches as string

Tags: regex, powershell

Given a string:

```
$assemblyVersion = '[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.0.0.866")]'
```

I have a regex that will find the assembly numbers:

```
(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)
```

These lines confirms it has found a match:

```
$extractedVersion = $assemblyVersion -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)";
```

How do you then extract the match from the original string `$assemblyVersion`?

Reading [this article](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) i don't quite get how you do it...

I tried:

```
$assemblyVersion

$extractedVersion = $assemblyVersion -match "?<assembly>(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)";

Write-Host "Extracted " $extractedVersion["assembly"]
```

Doesn't work.

My regex may not be optimal either.

This stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881573/regular-expression-matching-in-powershell) doesn't help

Comment: I've already said that the question you have referenced doesn't answer my question... It isn't the answer. I have posted the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
$assemblyVersion = '[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.0.0.866")]'

$assemblyVersion -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)";

Write-Host "Extracted " $matches[0]
```